# How can I check if the current locale uses AM/PM or 24-hour time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, locale

I'm trying to update a string which should display the time differently depending on whether the current locale uses AM/PM or 24-hours

If the locale can be determined I can then update the time string using `strftime("%I:%M %p")` or `strftime("%H:%M")` depending on the locale

**How can I programatically determine if the current locale uses AM/PM or 24-hour time?**

Or is there a better way to reach the same goal (displaying a time differently depending on which locale my software is running on)?

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: Given that the "locale appropriate time" for `en_US` in [the `strftime`/`strptime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is rendered with a 24 hour clock (`%X` produces `21:30:00` under `en_US` locale), I doubt the Python locale information indicates whether the local standard is 12 or 24 hour clock. The U.S. is nearly 100% 12 hour clock, but the locale time representation is 24 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `time.strftime()` function with the `%p` parameter will give the equivalent for AM/PM in the current locale, and for locales that don't use AM/PM an empty string is returned. I use this in the following way:

```
time_format_string = "%H:%M"  # Ex: Sweden
if time.strftime("%p"):  # Checking if the string contains something
    time_format_string = "%I:%M %p"  # Ex: US
time_of_day_string = time.strftime(time_format_string)
print(time_of_day_string)
```

I've tried this for two locales (one with and another without AM/PM)

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 1):

Tord, the behavior is odd, but this worked on Windows 7. Note that prior to setting the locale the time displayed as 24hour clock. Once locale was set it displayed using the 12hour AM/PM setting. That is the correct setting from my laptop.

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> import time
>>> cur_locale = locale.getlocale() # current locale setting
>>> cur_locale
('English_United States', '1252')
>>> time.strftime("%X") # %X - Locale’s appropriate time representation
'20:01:47'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, cur_locale)
'English_United States.1252'
>>> time.strftime("%X") # %X - Locale’s appropriate time representation
'8:02:11 PM'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. Okay, i get similar behavior on Ubuntu 16.04: AM/PM is added to the end of the output string only after using setlocale

Comment: Your answer made me dig further and write my own answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclaimer 1: This was tested only on GNU/Linux with glibc. Your mileage may vary on Windows, macOS, Linux with non-GNU libc and on other operating systems.</sub>

<sub>Disclaimer 2: I tested this on Alpine Linux with musl libc and it does not work. You may encounter this when using Docker since Alpine is very popular for making minimalistic container images.</sub>

---

### tl;dr

Use this:

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale.getdefaultlocale(("LC_TIME",)))
```

### The problem

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864935#comment70913507_41864935) by [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696) drew my attention:

> Given that the "locale appropriate time" for `en_US` in [the `strftime`/`strptime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is rendered with a 24 hour clock (`%X` produces `21:30:00` under `en_US` locale), I doubt the Python locale information indicates whether the local standard is 12 or 24 hour clock. The U.S. is nearly 100% 12 hour clock, but the locale time representation is 24 hour.

Let's try to find out what's going on here.

A documentation for [locale.getdefaultlocale()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale) function gives us a hint:

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` runs using the portable `'C'` locale.

It looks like CPython uses the `'C'` locale by default, and its time representation seems to be 24-hour:

```sh
$ LC_TIME=C date
Tue Oct 27 13:06:54 UTC 2020
$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date
Tue Oct 27 01:06:54 PM UTC 2020
$ TZ=UTC LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 date
Di 27. Okt 13:06:54 UTC 2020
```

Let's confirm this:

```py
$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 python3
>>> import locale
>>> import time
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
(None, None)
>>> time.strftime("%p")
'PM'
>>> time.strftime("%X")
'13:03:34'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
'C'
>>> locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
(None, None)
```

Here we can see two things:

1. Having the default locale unset is the same as having it set to `'C'`.
2. Setting the `LC_TIME` environment variable without using it explicitly in Python does not give any effect.

<sub>I wonder why `%p` is set if `%X` does not use it? ️</sub>

### The solution

To make the program honour our locale preferences, we need to call `locale.setlocale()` and supply it with `LC_TIME`.

```py
$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 python3
>>> import locale
>>> import time
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale.getdefaultlocale(('LC_TIME',)))
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> time.strftime("%p")
'PM'
>>> time.strftime("%X")
'01:03:59 PM'
```

```py
$ LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 python3
>>> import locale
>>> import time
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale.getdefaultlocale(('LC_TIME',)))
'de_DE.UTF-8'
>>> time.strftime("%p")
''
>>> time.strftime("%X")
'13:06:13'
```